# Extracting java source code from WAR files

Tags: java, war

Is there a way to extract java source code from WAR files?

I have tried using different mechanisms to extract the source code, but it yielded no desired results. I used command prompt it seems there was some extraction but upon examination of the extracted files nothing of interest was there.

Comment: Try some decompilers like http://java-decompiler.github.io/

Comment: a war file (and jar4 files) are zip files.  If you rename the extension, you can open windows explorer.  But whether there is source code in that file or not is a different matter.

Comment: I would be very surprised to find *actual* source code inside a WAR file.

Comment: WAR files usually contain compiled Java classes, i.e. files with the `.class` extension, and those files contain [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) and not source code. You can extract the `.class` files - one way is to use the [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jar.html) command - and then [decompile](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2021/11/13-best-java-decompilers-for-download-and-online-use-for-java-developers.html) them.

Comment: There shouldn't be any Java source code *in* the WAR file if it has been competently constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Just Rename the .war file extension to .zip. This allow you to treat the WAR file as a regular ZIP archive.
Use a file extraction tool or utility such as winrar to extract the contents of the renamed WAR file.
Once extracted, navigate to WEB-INF/src or src directory and look for files with the .java extension

enjoy!